# Mockito: how to stub inherited methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jetty, mockito

I am using [Jetty client API](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.3.v20150827/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpClient.html) on my application and I want to test my following code using Junit and Mockito:

```
public void startHttpClient(){
    try {
        httpClient.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My test case is the following:

```
@Mock HttpClient httpClient;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    testBackend= new TestBackend(3,httpClient); 
}
@Test
public void teststartHttpClient() throws Exception {

    testBackend.startHttpClient();
    assertNotNull(httpClient);
    verify(httpClient,atLeastOnce()).start();

}
```

The problem is that the Mock HttpClient inherit the start() method from AbstractLifeCycle, so I got a null pointer exception on the AbstractLifeCycle class:
How can I mock the inherited method start() call fot the class HttpClient?

The Exception got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:61)
    at test.TestBackendTest.teststartHttpClient(TestBackendTest.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: start is a final method. It can't be mocked by Mockito.

Comment: Where are you passing your mock into the code under the test? Why is there not a setter or constructor argument for the HttpClient?

Comment: Why do you want to mock Jetty's HttpClient?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: I want to do a code coverage of my application that is using Jetty client API. In this example my method startHttpClient() calls the  HttpClient.start() method that is why I need to mock it.

Comment: Without the HttpClient lifecycle operating (what `HttpClient.start()` initiates), you'll never get a clear picture of your code coverage, as there's plenty of listeners, callbacks, and futures that would be tricky to mock properly (probably wind up writing 20x more mocking code than if you had just used HttpClient itself)

Comment: @BretC: you are right, my fault, thanks! But still have the problem since it is dependant to HttpClient lifecycle as **Joakim Erdeflt** said and also the problem of the final method start() as **JB Nizet** said.